# VHDL buffer variable vs out variable

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

I work in a VHDL program and I need to do a RAM 256 using the ALTERA DE2-115. The outputs will show in a seven segment display.
The problem is that: I have a `dataout` output variable. Then the variable has the following values of the `temp_ram` array:

```
dataout <= temp_ram(conv_integer(dir));
```

Then I want to divide the vaules of `dataout` to put in the seven segment

```
dataout(7 downto 4)
dataout(3 downto 0)
```

This shows the following error:

```
Error (10309): VHDL Interface Declaration error in RAM.vhd(45): interface object "dataout" of mode out cannot be read. Change object mode to buffer.
```

When I change to buffer and this run prefect, but I can't understand what happen

Comment: See [VHDL Interface Declaration error in <location>: interface object "<name>" of mode out cannot be read. Change object mode to buffer.    (ID: 10309)](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_vhdl_read_from_out.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cross-platform compatibility and code-reusability, I'd recommend an **intermediate signal** ( dataout_int can be used by other statements) :

```
    dataout_int <= temp_ram(conv_integer(dir));
```

and assign the output to this intermediate signal:

```
    dataout <= dataout_int;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `conv_integer` from a Synopsys package. Please use only official IEEE packages.

`dataout` is a signal, not a variable, because you use a *signal assignment statement*. Moreover, the signal is a port of mode `out`. (Ports are signals as well).

Besides static typing, VHDL is also checking directions of signal in ports. Your signal is of mode `out` so it can't be read.

**Als a solution, you can:**

- use an intermediate signal,
- use mode `buffer`, which is not supported by all synthesis tools equally
- use VHDL-2008, which allows ports of mode `out` to be read.

Quartus support some VHDL-2008 features.

Comment: Before -2002 a port of mode `buffer` formal associated with an actual that is a port could only be associated with a port of mode `buffer`. That can raise the question of the revision level of the VHDL tool when an output of mode `buffer` connection traverses multiple interfaces upward in a design hierarchy.

Comment: See [Brian's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129747/trying-to-use-a-buffer-in-vhdl-not-working/27130438#27130438) to [Trying to use a buffer in VHDL - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129747/trying-to-use-a-buffer-in-vhdl-not-working).